# Jquery replace img class src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am hoping to find out why the following code does not work:

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myimg").attr("src", "image2.jpg");
     });
  </script>

  <div>
     <img class = "myimg" src = "image1.jpg" alt = "Sample image" />
  </div>
```

while this block does:

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myimg").attr("src", "image2.jpg");
     });
  </script>

  <div>
     <img id= "myimg" src = "image1.jpg" alt = "Sample image" />
  </div>
```

Comment: how is that second block working with two src attributes?

Comment: Because there's no ID in the second example.

Comment: Are you sure second one works? you're selecting element with myimg id, but non of your examples has it.

Comment: sorry - i was typing it wrong - the solution is indeed the ".myimg"

Comment: ID is referred by `#`, and class is referred by `.` Thus first one does not work, and second one does.

Answer (score 1):

In your html in the first block you need to set the id of the img tag to myimg:

```
<img id="myimg">
```

If you're going to call it with `$('#myimg')`

You can also just change your jquery to call it like:

```
$('.myimg')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's messed up, but the error in your first example is you are looking for an element with an id #myimg instead of a class .myimg